# Developing Performance Automation Framework

Tags: performance, frameworks, automation

I want to develop automated performance framework for performing load/stress testing on web application.I tried using Jmeter webdriver and also reusing selenium existing scripts for performance testing. But the concern is, i do not want to use any performance tool(Jmeter/Loadrunner) for writing or executing the scripts.
For eg: Selenium IDE can record the browser action in script format and later it can be executed. But the other way is, functional scripts can be created using eclipse after configuring selenium JAR files and while running those scripts test data can be read from any xls/txt file.

Does similar kind of thing is possible for creating performance testing framework i.e performance scripts can be written using some editor(eclipse/visual studio...etc)other than performance tool and the required data can be read from external file(xls/txt)?? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention nothing about the language - I could advice you to take a look at the [VisualStudio Ultimate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It has everything you need and is build-in. You can record web tests, extend those with specific web requests, add data-driven approach and manage all that from a single MS MSQL DB (even the free Express edition). But the thing that is more likely to help you with the

> the required data can be read from external file(xls)

is that not only you can read, but also export vast number of metrics in such format. So the reporting is in business friendly view.

Comment: Thank You for reply...
Preferred language is Java. Is there any  open source tool for performing above mentioned thing??

Comment: No that I know about. You can try JMeter, but is pretty bone-dry compared to VS. There are options to extend and add features, but on what cost!? If just the OOP language is stopping you - on QA level there are almost no differences. Cheers